# In the context of using Kafka and Apache Beam, what is the difference between a Coder and Kafka Deserializer?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-beam

I'm new to Apache Beam. I'm trying to read data from Kafka by using `KafKaIO` as per the documentation. During the creation of a `PCollection`, the `withValueDeserializerAndCoder` method allows you to set a coder and a deserializer. I couldn't understand why we might require both deserializer and a coder. In my mind, both are about representing byte streams as java objects. So why do we need both? Is it because Beam is more of a framework that allows multiple runners underneath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a bit tricky and not obvious at first sight. You need to have a Kafka `Deserializer` (or `Serializer` if you write into Kafka) to interpret key and value bytes to Java objects that you read from Kafka. In the same time, Beam requires us to provide `Coder`s to materialize the intermediate data of our `PCollection`s in the runtime.

Coders are not related to (de)serializers (that are responsible to interpret Kafka messages), so we need to provide coders explicitly. Though, `KafkaIO` will try to infer a coder from deserializer and it will work in many cases implicitly, but if it fails or your want to provide a specific coder then you can specify it separately.

For example, if your Kafka messages are serialised with Avro format, you can use `KafkaAvroDeserializer` and internal Beam `AvroCoder`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
...
  KafkaIO.Read read = KafkaIO.<Long, MyClass>read()
      .withKeyDeserializer(LongDeserializer.class)
      .withValueDeserializerAndCoder((Class) KafkaAvroDeserializer.class,
          AvroCoder.of(MyClass.class));
...
}

@DefaultCoder(AvroCoder.class) 
public class MyClass {

  String name;
  String age;

  MyClass() {}

  MyClass(String n, String a) {
    this.name = n;
    this.age = a;
  }
}
```